# Excel: look across array and return nth non-"n.a." value

Tags: excel

in row 3, I have an array of data that contains numerical values and text in the form of "n.a.". I would be most appreciative if someone could help me construct a formula that looks across the array and returns the nth non-"n.a." value.

Row 3 beginning in column B: 5, 8, n.a., 7, 6 ,3, 9, 7, n.a., 12

Formula would return 7 if n was set to 3.

Formula would return 12 if n was set to 9.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the bold, italic ***3*** in the formula as your n value:

=INDEX(3:3,SMALL(INDEX(ISNUMBER(B3:K3)*COLUMN(B3:K3),),***3***+COUNTA(B3:K3)-COUNT(B3:K3)))

Note that given your example, setting n to 9 will result in a #NUM! error because there are only 8 numbers.  Expand the B3:K3 to suit your range, but do not use a whole row reference (using whole row reference would greatly decrease performance time).  If preferred, you could create a dynamic named range instead of manually setting the B3:K3 range.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work for me. I've slightly tweaked the formula for the real data (please see below). For most of the rows I have copied this down for, it appears to return the number in the last cell that isn't an n.a.

=INDEX($S11:$AL11,SMALL(INDEX(ISNUMBER($S11:$AL11)*COLUMN($S11:$AL11),),AW$9+COUNTA($S11:$AL11)-COUNT($S11:$AL11)))

Comment: I couldn't quite get it to work either - I find that if there are n/a's further on so that count and counta are different, it affects the earlier positions in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=INDEX(3:3,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B3:K3)/ISNUMBER(B3:K3),3))
```

This formula comes almost directly from God, a.k.a. Scott Craner. The way it works is that any cells which don't contain a number will give a #DIV/0! error in the division. Any cells which do contain a number just give the column in B3:K3. Aggregate with 15,6 works like SMALL but ignores the error cells thus giving you the answer you want.